# Orthogonal Projection in subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, orthogonality

> Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ with usual inner product
>   $<.,.>$. Take $Y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>   $Y=[y_1,y_2,..y_n]^t$ and $X=[1,1,....1]^t$
>
> Determine the orthogonal projection of $Y$ in the subspace generated
>   by $X$.What can be concluded?

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, and $U = \text{span}\{X\} = $ subspace generated by $X$.

One of the first results about inner-product spaces is that we can always decompose $V$ into 
\begin{equation}
V = U \oplus U^{\perp},
\end{equation}
 where $U^{\perp} = \{v \in V\,:\, \langle v, u\rangle = 0,\, \forall u \in U\}$ is the set of all vectors which are orthogonal to $U$.

That is, for any $v \in V$, there is a unique $u \in U$ and $w \in U^{\perp}$ such that $v = u + w$.

***The orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $U$ is by definition the vector $u$.***

**How to determine this $u$ from a given $v$?**

Suppose $(e_1,\ldots, e_m)$ is an orthonormal basis for $U$ (such a basis always exists). By extending this basis to an orthonormal basis $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ for $V$, it is easy to see (good exercise) that this vector $u$ is actually 
\begin{equation}
u = \langle v, e_1\rangle e_1 + \ldots + \langle v, e_m\rangle e_m
\end{equation}

**How to apply this to the question?**

In the question, $U = \text{span}\{X\}$. So what is an orthonormal basis for $U$?

Once you have this orthonormal basis, you can calculate the orthogonal projection of $Y$ onto $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to produce an orthonormal basis for $\operatorname{Span}(X)$:
$$\hat X\frac1{\|X\|}X = \frac1{\langle X,X\rangle^{\frac12}}X=\frac1{\sqrt n}X. $$
The projection of $Y$ onto $\operatorname{Span}(X)$ is simply
$$\langle \hat X,Y\rangle \hat X=\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) X. $$